# Link to CSS not showing up on my Git Hub gh-pages

Tags: html, css

For some reason my CSS is not showing up on my Git Hub page.
I read through some of the stuff that has been posted in the past but it don't seem to work.
Also, I have another project that I am working on shows up but for this particular project nothing is showing.
Could it be something wrong with my link tag?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
```

Please help.

Comment: Your tag looks fine.  Do you have a link to the repo or more information?  Otherwise you should be able to use your browsers developer tools to figure out what path it's looking for styles.css in.

Comment: Does the CSS file exist in the linked location?

Comment: here are the errors I am receiving:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - https://dtrinh888.github.io/shopping-list/css/styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).  That's what I got when I used the developer tools

Comment: I see what the problem is. When I checked on the developer tools the css portion was blank. What did I do to make it blank because when I look at the repository the css is there.